# INSERT into table ON CONFLICT increase other column value -> column reference is ambigous? SOLVED

Tags: postgresql-15

I have a large sourceTable (300 Million rows) with several columns:

id  sequence orientation  gc_content – etc

most sequences appear only once in the table, but others might be in there much more often

I need to know how often each sequence appears in the sourceTable, so I created a table targetTable with 3 columns:

id  sequence  frequency

The column sequence has been set to be unique.

I filled this targetTable with all distinct sequence values and set the frequency to 0 by default in each.

Now I want to select all the sequences from the sourceTable and "insert" them into the targetTable (which can't happen) and ON CONFLICT increase the frequency for that sequence by 1 (not sure that is the most intelligent way of going about it).

The code works fine for the first part

```sql
INSERT INTO targetTable (sequence, frequency)
(SELECT sequence, 1
FROM sourceTable)
ON CONFLICT (sequence)
DO NOTHING
```

but when I try

```sql
INSERT INTO targetTable (sequence, frequency)
(SELECT sequence, 1
FROM sourceTable)
ON CONFLICT (sequence)
--DO NOTHING
DO UPDATE SET
frequency = targetTable.frequency + 1
WHERE
sequence = targetTable.sequence -- = sourceTable.sequence
;
```

I get the message that **sequence is ambiguous**.

To make sequence not ambiguous I tried

```sql
WHERE
targetTable.sequence = sourceTable.sequence
```

and

```sql
WHERE
sourceTable.sequence = targetTable.sequence
```

but then I get "**ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "sourceTable"** "

What am I missing here?

Thanks for any advice - I would have liked to figure that one out on my own as it seems like a common problem that should be easy to research on the internet, but I banged my head against that since yesterday morning and am running out of time …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual table associated with failed `INSERT` rows is named `EXCLUDED`, so the SQL would be as follows, except that each row can only be affected once:

```
INSERT INTO targetTable (sequence, frequency)
SELECT sequence, 1
  FROM sourceTable
ON CONFLICT (sequence)
  DO UPDATE SET frequency = targetTable.frequency + 1
  WHERE EXCLUDED.sequence = targetTable.sequence;
```

This is documented in [PostgreSQL 15 Documention - INSERT SQL Command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html). Note, the `SELECT` clause didn't need to be enclosed in parentheses. Avoid using `sequence` as a column identifier since it is a SQL key word.

A proper approach to get the counts would be to use the `COUNT` aggregate function grouped by `sequence`:

```
INSERT INTO targetTable(sequence, frequency)
SELECT sequence, COUNT(*) AS frequency
  FROM sourceTable
  GROUP BY sequence;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that results in another error: "ERROR:  ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time"

Comment: @MarkusWinter, after I posted, I realized that I neglected to include that detail. I've revised my answer with a working solution as well as my original response addressing the ambiguous column exception.

Comment: Thanks John, the second solution works beautifully and very quickly too! 40 sec for a table with 33 Million rows on my 13 year old Mac (from 2010!). Perfect!